# How to calculate size of Dynamic Heap Allocations in objective-c/c?

Tags: c, objective-c, memory, heap-memory

I want to get the size of heap allocations (live) with Objective-C/C code. As we can see these allocations in XCode instruments. How can we get this information with code?

I want currently live objects size in HEAP which are being allocated by my app..? I have resident memory set info but that is not not help full.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux you can use the difference from `end` to `sbrk(0)` to determine the current size of your heap:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern char etext, edata, end;

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("First address past:\n");
    printf("    program text (etext)      %10p\n", &etext);
    printf("    initialized data (edata)  %10p\n", &edata);
    printf("    uninitialized data (end)  %10p\n", &end);

    printf("    Heap Size (sbrk() - end)  %10p\n", sbrk(0) - (void *)&end);

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This works because in Linux the heap starts directly after the BSS segment.

**Edit:**

If you are looking for the resident set (the amount of physical memory currently in use by our process) then for Linux you need to read it from `/proc/self/stat` (sadly the field in `getrusage` is discontinued):

```
FILE *fpstat = fopen("/proc/self/stat", "r");
long int rss;
fscanf(fpstat, "%*d %*s %*c %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %l*u"
            "%l*u %l*d %l*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*u %l*u %ld", &rss);
rss *= sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE); // to get memory in bytes
```

For OS X there is a native Mach method for this:

```
struct task_basic_info t_info;
mach_msg_type_number_t t_info_count = TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT;

task_info(MACH_PORT_NULL, TASK_BASIC_INFO, (task_info_t)&t_info, &t_info_count);
size_t rss = t_info.resident_size;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I want to get my whole app allocation size. Some thing global to whom I ask what is the current allocation size of the app/program? is there any way?

Comment: @C_X I am sorry, but your question was wrongly asked there is far more to a processes memory then just it's heap. In that case you are looking for the resident set and not just heap: For Linux consult field 24 in `/proc/self/stat` and multiply it by `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`. For OS X `task_info` will query the RSS for you directly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Nope I don't want that, I have those things but resident memory is not giving what exactly i Heap Allocation. Actually resident memory is much more than what your live allocations are. I am sorry If I could not made this more explainable.

Comment: @C_X So what is it what you really want? Could you maybe rephrase your question and say what you really want?

Comment: I am using that native mach method to get resident memory and virtual memory. But this is not solution. There is one way if I start counting the size of my allocations, but that will also not enough, then I have also count the de-allocations to get live Objects residing in heap. So I was looking for some thing helpful in c or objective-c which can calculate live objects and there size.